# Install .NET Core 2.2 preview binaries on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, asp.net-core, deployment, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I want to deploy a ASP.NET Core 2.2 application to a DigitalOcean droplet running Ubuntu 18.04.

When deploying .NET Core 2.1 applications in the past, I've used the [Package Manager Instructions](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/linux-package-manager/rhel/runtime-2.1.5) with no problems, but they are not yet available for 2.2.

I've naively tried changing `2.1` to `2.2` in the Package Manager Instructions with no luck.

Is it possible to install the binaries manually?

Thanks!

Comment: Those steps are for production versions. For 2.2 preview, you have to follow something else. Download from https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/2.2 and then the download page tells more.

Comment: I was able to find these downloads myself, but I'm confused what to do exactly with these runtime `tar.gz` binaries.

Comment: Don't close your browser after downloading the package, as the extra steps are displayed there. Download it again if you missed that page.

Comment: Ah, the instructions only show when downloading the SDK, not the runtimes. I followed the instructions and my .NET Core 2.2 app is now up and running!
Thank you very much.